# HTML Div tag not showing in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: html

I have three div tags wraps on my website and in those wraps i have multiple other div tags aligned under each other. When I started working on the right column div tag wrap and when i had put my inner div tag in that one it didnt show on FireFox although I coded it the same as the left and center one.

Code of the right column divtag wrap:

```
<div id="right_column_wrap">
    <div id="advertisement_panel">
    <img src="images/advertisement_h1.png" />
    <p class="advertisement_panel">Want your website featured here? Mail us at info@Ranklist-Top100.com</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#right_column_wrap{
    width:312px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
}
#advertisement_panel{
    background:url('http://www.ranklist-top100.com/skins/ranklist/images/advertisement_panel-bg.png') no-repeat top;
    width:312px;
    height:710px;
    float:right;
}
.advertisement_panel{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

I hope I supplied you guys with enough information =)

Comment: please supply a screenshot of what you're viewing, also which version of FF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miro is right. Your image gets blocked by 'adblock plus' - this will quite probably be the same for the majority of your users.

Try to use that background file locally and name it something different from 'advertisement_panel'.

Comment: Thanks! It works now, I am going to rename it into something else. Thanks :)

Comment: As I said in my very first sentence: "Miro is right. " :-)
+1 for you

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong in Firefox - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qn7cB/).

But i have to turn off adblock plus, because it blocks that image.